# Handling concurrent requests for Kubernetes cluster on azure

Tags: nginx, flask, queue, gunicorn, azure-aks

What is the best option to handle concurrent requests within a kubernetes cluster? In the specific I am using AKS on azure.

My current setting has multiple pods of my API implemented with FLASK+GUNICORN, together with a nginx reverse proxy (also instanziated with multiple pods).
I would have expected that the nginx´s loadbalancer service would already take care of redirecting requests to pods with lower traffic, but what I see is that it actually happens often that two consequtives requests land on the same nginx pod, with consequent waiting time.

Should I implement a queue handler? If so, which option is the best? Is there an azure native service which could be integrated in AKS?

Or could be enough to implement a readiness probe for my pods? If so, what would be the best set up? A GUNICORN worker with 2 threads, and a simple check endpoint for my API?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a special requirement I would start by removing the Nginx reverse proxy, and relying on a normal kubernetes Service if the traffic is for intra cluster access only, and using a Service with Ingress if it's for external access.

The reason for this is that unless you've been very careful when configuring the Nginx reverse proxy, it's likely not working optimally. For example when accessing this service remotely NAT'ing will be performed, having an extra Nginx in there will likely pin the requests to a single session/IP because of the NAT'ing, thus having multiple new requests being repeatedly sent to the same backend. The Nginx ingress supports a number of annotations to help configure this, namely:

- [Session Affinity](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#session-affinity)
- [Custom NGINX upstream hashing](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-nginx-upstream-hashing)
- [Custom NGINX load balancing](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-nginx-load-balancing)

The [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) could also be a good fit for this situation; as this would allow your app to scale with demand (within a configured set of limits). IMO this would be a preferable approach to implementing a queue, if you prefer that processing happen as close to real-time as possible. If you don't mind having some longer delay added for processing, then a worker queue model might be a better fit as it will likely require less resources.

As you have touched on, you should set up readiness and liveness probes for your app, so that Kubernetes can better understand their health. Readiness probes are what kubernetes uses to understand whether to consider a pod ready to accepting traffic, and thus affect whether a service will route traffic to a pod or not. Liveness checks let kubernetes understand when/if it should restart a pod, this is useful for restarting after an unrecoverable condition halts a pod.

Here are some references for further reading on kubernetes probes:

- [Container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)
- [Configure Liveness and Readiness Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)
- [Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes: How to Avoid Shooting Yourself in the Foot](https://blog.colinbreck.com/kubernetes-liveness-and-readiness-probes-how-to-avoid-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can imagine it would be easier to rely on an Ingress, but for the moment it would require more effort than the resulting gain. Is there any reference about optimal configuration of the nginx proxy? In any case I am already trying to see if it comes any relevant improvement with the right readiness probe.